# Moving app data layer from using Entity Framewok to use a Web API

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, migration

**Summary**

I have an application which is built with WPF and EF6 (SQL Server Compact 4.0 database file).

The app is already deployed at customer site. The customer wants to migrate the local database to an online database.

Because it is not secure to connect remotely over the internet to my online mysql database, I used the open source PHP CRUD API and deployed it to my linux server.

**The Problem**

I have about 30 tables and thus models classes. Each table has more than 5 methods in its repository class.

Now when using API, I cannot directly use Entity Framework methods such as `SaveChanges()`, `Add()`, `AddRange()`  etc... , instead, I'm using the model classes for the API and serializing/deserializing the model objects to Json and from Json.

This process requires a lot of work and time to migrate all 30 tables and rewrite all there related repository classes to get and set data from the API, taking into consideration the complexity of the entity relations.

**Questions**

1. Is this the correct way to migrate from local to online database ?
2. What is the most effective way to migrate an app with existing local database with EF 6 an online mysql database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Because it is not secure to connect remotely over the internet to my online mysql database"

Why not? There are ways to secure an online database. You can host the db in the cloud, and securely open a port to only a range of ip addresses that the current customer has, or setup a vpn from the customer to the database.

If you must use a webapi you can put your ef layer under the webapi, and expose the webapi endpoints to the client for your crud methods. When you call the web api endpoint, you send the same models you have now, and the web api uses ef like it does in the thick client. You still have to secure the webapi endpoints to callers that you trust.

Comment: Hi Louis , 
For this projects im not allowed to use the customers cloud server , instead they want me to use a shared hosting server, the customer public ip address is not static,so i should allow a range of ip's which i do not prefer. , and it requires me to install the mysql connector at customer site which i used before and it didn't perform well.  so i still prefer to use the API , for the API option , **"can you please explain how it will be in action if i put the ef layer under the webapi"** ?